# Google Voice—change audio device

Tags: google-talk

I need to change the audio device used by Google Voice chat.

[The official help page](http://support.google.com/chat/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162176&topic=24673&ctx=topic) says "Click the Options button at the bottom of your chat list". The problem is, there’s no such button in either Opera or IE10. I’m using Windows 8 x64. Here's a screenshot of my chat list:

[image]

I have the plugin installed. Voice+video works but I can't hear anything due to the wrong device.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Gmail settings and then click on the *Chat* tab. There you will be able to change the audio device and also test the sound device.